# Change Parent of a Branch

Tags: git, rebase

I have Branch a branch **A** checked out from **master** branch.then i have a branch **B** Checked out from branch **A** .

I want to change the parent of branch **B** to **master**

Current Tree

```
         master
        /
       A
      /
     B
```

Should Be

```
     master
     /   \
    A     B
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git checkout B
git rebase A --onto master
```

Comment: what if i pushed the code to remote and i want same changes on remote as well?

Comment: `git push --force` (assuming the server will allow it.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command to change your parent branch:

```
git rebase --onto new_parent_branch old_parent_branch
```

In your case, use these commands:

1. `git checkout B`
2. `git rebase --onto master A`